# Laravel return last users

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I was wondering, what is the simplest way to return last 3 users from database and show them in homepage with Laravel Framework. I have this column, last three registred users/companies and i want to show users name and more info.

Comment: Keep in mind that "latest" can mean a bunch of different things; latest created, latest edited, latest to login, etc etc. For your case, registration would coincide with "created", so using `id` or `created_at` would likely be the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `latest()` and `take()` methods:

```
User::latest()->take(3)->get();
```

`latest()` is a shortcut for `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')`, so you also can do this:

```
User::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(3)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do a scope in the User model :

```
public function scopeLast($query){
    return $query->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(3);
}
```

Considering that id is auto-incremented, if not, use the created_at column instead of the id column inside the orderBy

Use it like this :

```
User::last()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way could be :

```
$latestUsers = DB::table('users')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(3)->get();
```

But I would prefer this method :

1. You need to have a Users Model
2. You need to import it inside the controller

then you should write this :

```
$latestUsers = User::orderBy('id','desc')->limit(3)->get();
```

or

```
 $latestUsers = User::latest()->limit(3)->get();
```